# How to integrate with square root, fraction and ln?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I need help with ideas on solving this integral that's a part of originally my differential equation.

$r' = \pm \sqrt {2ln |(n+kr^l)| + C}$, where C, n, k and l are constants

$\frac {dr(z)}{dz} = \pm \sqrt {2ln |(n+kr^l)| + C}$, where r(z) = r

$\int {dz} = \pm \int {\frac{1}{\sqrt {2ln |(n+kr^l)| + C}} dr}$

$z+c = \pm \int {\frac{1}{\sqrt {2ln |(n+kr^l)| + C}} dr}$

And the RHS is where I'm stuck. I tried substituting and that couldn't work. I'm out of ideas that I can try that would be applicable to this.

Comment: Do you have initial data? You might be able to simplify the expression.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have any initial data. That would indeed be very helpful.